# yii2 doesnot store Cookie in localhost or server

Tags: php, session-cookies, yii2-advanced-app

I write this below code in a different controller to store cookies

```
         $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
        $number=0;
        if($cookies->has('registration_id')){
            if($cookies->has('registration_attempt')){
                $registration_att =               $cookies->getValue('registration_attempt');
                $number = $registration_att+1;
                $cookies->add( new Cookie([
                    'name' => 'registration_attempt',
                    'value' => $number,
                    'expire' => time() + 86400*2,
                ]));
            }
            else{
                $cookies->add( new Cookie([
                    'name' => 'registration_attempt',
                    'value' => $number,
                    'expire' => time() + 86400*2,
                ]));
            }

        } else{



            $cookies->add(new Cookie([
                'name' => 'registration_id',
                'value' => 'Generate Id',
                'expire' => time() + 86400*2,
            ]));
            $cookies->add( new Cookie([
                'name' => 'registration_attempt',
                'value' => $number+1,
                'expire' => time() + 86400*2,
            ]));

         //**show here**
        }
```

I set secure true but it does not show anything in different controller . When i am trying to access cookies value it shows null. Cookie value set but it doesn't set globally . Instant show cookie value where I commented **show here**. I am checking here if cookie set then if either else and always hit that. And if echo in that place it show data .

Comment: This line may be wrong:

    $number = registration_att+1;

Should be...

    $number = $cookie_registration_att + 1;

Comment: its my typing mistake, now its correct

Comment: Don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you write some code instead of "show here" and be more specific. Could be that the cookie value is not saved until the response is sent, ie at the end of the application life cycle.